# Custom objective function for Keras multiclass network

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, keras

I'm making a neural network that'll classify multiple bluetooth RSSI values into certain locations.

For example, this is the normalized RSS input from multiple bluetooth receivers:

```
[0.1, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.8, 0.6599999999999999, 0.9, 0.36317567567567566]
```

And this would be the output, classifying it into a location:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

This is the model:

```
# create model
model = Sequential()

# Input layer has 12 inputs and 24 neurons
model.add(Dense(24, input_dim=12, init='normal', activation='relu'))

# Output layer, has 11 outputs
model.add(Dense(11, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))

# Compile model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I train the network with 3226 training samples, and test it afterwards with 263 extra samples.

After the first 50 epochs the training samples have an accuracy of about 85%. The test samples are then about 74% accurate.

But if I continue on training, the accuracy of the test samples actually goes **down**. 50 more epochs of testing will result in an 88% accuracy of the training samples and a 62% accuracy in the test samples.

I've tried multiple objective functions, but the result is the same: the more I train, the worse it gets.

Could this be due to the loss function that tries to be *too binary*, perhaps?

Is there a loss function available that would positively reward the result if the correct class just has the highest value of them all?

Comment: Try reducing your learning rate for the Adam optimizer. Also try to get more data.